# Checking equality of Arrays by values in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

**I WOULD LIKE TO AVOID USING LINQ IF POSSIBLE**

I have a `List<int[]>` of 2 integers that represent coordinate pairs on a grid. Eg:

`List<int[]> coords = new List<int[]>` which grows and shrinks very often as it is iterated over. These values represent cells that are on fire (its a console-based burning forest simulator). As the fire spreads, I update the list and remove the previously burning list elements. My problem comes from having duplicate values, and being unable to rapidly check for this and get it fixed.

I have tried using `coords.Distinct()` but it did not work as `int[]` are not simple types, and I don't know C# well enough to start using LINQ and all that stuff and since this is due in a few days, I don't really have the time, patience, inclination or stress level to dive into it. I did try to get it to work, but it was equally ineffective.

```c
public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
{
     string stringx = string.Join(",", x);
     string stringy = string.Join(",", y);
     Console.WriteLine("x: " + stringx + "y: " + stringy);
     return stringx == stringy;
}
```

Currently this is my equality checker, as it seemed that changing them to strings and then comparing them would be faster than checking if the 0th and 1st element of each array are equal, but still I am getting duplicates in my list.

I call the `Equals()` method like this:

```c
foreach (KeyValuePair<int[], char> entry in returns)
{
     if (entry.Value == 'x')
     {
        foreach (int[] burn in burnzones)
        {
           if (!Equals(burn, entry.Key))
           {
              newburns.Add(entry.Key);
           }
        }
     }
}
```

`returns` is a dictionary of {coord, state (burning or not, represented as 'x'if burning), burnzones, is my list that is passed as a parameter into the function of `List<int[]>` typing and if it is both burning and not equal to an element already in the list, it gets added to a new list (newburns). It's a lot of code so I didn't want to include too much, but I'm happy to add anything that might clarify what is happening if there are gaps (I'm on about four hours of sleep from staying up last night trying to get this to work), so apologies.

Comment: there is `Distinct` with `comparer` parameter ... C# doesn't know how **you wana compare** arrays or List<T> - so it compares references

Comment: Consider using value tuples, as they come with built-in equality operators that do the right thing. That is, use `List<(int x, int y)>` rather than a two-element array. As a bonus this should do wonders for the readability of your code (as well as allocations, but that's probably not very important).

Comment: Note also that using a two-element array as a dictionary key is a very bad idea for two reasons: you are forced to supply a custom equality comparer to get the dictionary to work correct at all (and must correctly implement both its `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods) and you must remember to never change the contents of the arrays once they're used as keys, since dictionary keys need to be immutable for the dictionary to work correctly. Again, value tuples come with this built-in, but even your own custom `Coord` type would be preferable to arrays.

Comment: "I have a List<int[]> of 2 integers that represent coordinate pairs on a grid" - Please don't. Use a type that actually represents the data, like a `System.Drawing.Point`, a custom `Vector2i` type, or some third party type. A `(int x, int y)` is better than `int[]`, but not as good as an actual type IMHO.